# Styling Issue with Jquerymobile radio button label

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When I dynamically change the label of a radio button in jquerymobile the circle button disapears
HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="optiona" value="choice-1" checked="checked">
<label for="optiona" id="labela"></label>
```

JS

```
 $('label[for=optiona]').text('best option');
```

What might be the issue?

In chrome dev tool elements, I observed that the data-icon attribute for this radio button is **on** while for the other radio buttons(the ones created inline) displaying properly are set to **off**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/NkzSJ/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $('label[for=optiona]').find('.ui-btn-text').text('best option');       
});
```

Comment: Why do I have to do all dis to set the text property of a radio button, dis looks to me more of an hack than actually method of doing this

Comment: Because jQuery Mobile rebuilds HTML structure, label you created don't exist any more like that.